# gcloud-node to access bearer token?

Tags: gcloud-node

will the gcloud-node API give me the bearer token it is using?

I'm able to create signed urls with gcloud-node and the keyfile.json but I'm trying to follow the [resumable download docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#signing-resumable).  they suggest starting an upload on the server and passing the session to the client.  looks easy except for the header:

`Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token`

can i do something like gcs.getAuth after some kind of init?

thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered on github: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-node/issues/818

answer: yes, but not officially supported

```
var reqOpts = { uri: '...' }; // what you would pass to the request module

storage.makeAuthorizedRequest_(reqOpts, {
  onAuthorized: function(err, authorizedReqOpts) {
    // authorizedReqOpts.headers.Authorization = 'bearer token'
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, if you just need a token, use [google-auto-auth](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/google-auto-auth) :)